# Rails 3.2 form_for for all database entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'd like to create a page where I can edit all my entries at once.
For example, I have 10 devices, at that point, I'm creating a html table with at each row a device with the possibility to edit each line without having to do extra clicking.

I've already tried these things (index.html.erb)

```
<% @devices.each do |device| %>
<%= render 'form', locals: { device: @device }%>
or
<%= render 'form', :collection => :device %>
or
<%= render 'form', :device %>
<% end %>
```

And my form partial

```
<%= form_for @device do |f| %>
<td><%= f.submit %></td>
<td><%= f.name%></td>
<td><%= f.type</td>
<td>Style app</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<% end %>
```

But I'm still getting this error
    undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have tried it looks like you are very close. What if you try rendering it as a partial?

```
<% @devices.each do |device| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { device: device } %>
<% end %>
```

Another difference here is the scope of the `device` param on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your partial... You are rendering global variable, you need to render local variable...

So, this is your solution:

```
<% @devices.each do |device| %>
<tr>
    <%= render 'form', locals: { device: device }%>
</tr>
```

and

```
<%= form_for device do |f| %>
```

Here, you should only be using the @ in @devices... Nowhere else.

Edit: Don't forget your `<tr></tr>`

Comment: I think you mean instance variable where you say global variable.

Comment: Neither actually. @ means variable is reachable outside local scope, so I call it global. Maybe public is more accurate.

Comment: No, I think it is an instance variable of the view context.

Comment: Ok, no objection. The @device in the partial however is neither defined within nor out of context, so it will be nil.